# Spring Batch Dynamic Query JdbcPagingItemReader and Pass Data Between Steps

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a requirement using Spring Boot and Spring Batch where i need to read data from one database which returns the records like below

```
Id1  Select * from Table1
Id2  Select * from Table2
```

Each query will be executed in different database and  will return over 100k records
Below are the queries i am stuck with

1. Pass the query to the reader (i.e from one step to other step)
2. Dynamically read the queries and fetch the records using `JdbcPagingItemReader`, as each query would return > 100k records and write with item writer.

All the queries will return the same item/pojo.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Can you Please throw some light on this.

Comment: Sure! However, the question is not clear to me. You need to read the same data from two different tables and write them in another one? Is that correct?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thanks for reply.Let me be clear on my question. First query returns a column value which is again a sql query,which need to be executed in another database and read by pagination and insert them into a first database.Let me know if you need additional details

Answer (score 0):

> First query returns a column value which is again a sql query,which need to be executed in another database and read by pagination and insert them into a first database

In this case, you can proceed in two steps:

- Step 1 (tasklet): executes the first query and puts its result (the query to be executed by the reader) in the execution context
- Step 2 (chunk-oriented): Reads the query from the execution context and passes the query dynamically to the reader

Comment: Thanks.Is it possible to provide a pseudo code for the same.As i am not sure on how to store  the result from first step into execution context and pass the same into reaader in step 2

Comment: Please check this section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps it provides code examples of how to share data between steps.

Answer (score 0):

*Have to create query using Placeholder(?)*

*EX Query-SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE status=? AND name=?*

Create ItemStreamReader :-

```
@Bean
public ItemStreamReader<Product> reader() {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Product> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    reader.setDataSource(DataSource);
    reader.setSql(SELECT_QUERY);
    reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new InputSetter());
    reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Product.class));
    return reader;
}
```

Create one Implementer class for PreparedStatementSetter interface

```
public class InputSetter implements PreparedStatementSetter {
@Override
public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
    ps.setString(1, "status");
    ps.setString(2,"Name");

}
```

}